Looking for unused/underused Java code types
We have a big Java project with thousands of source files.
Recently, I encountered a type that is not used anywhere.
It got me wondering how many of them we got.
Is there some tool to detect unused and underused types?
What I have:

IntelliJ Community 2024.1 (its code inspection is very slow, sometimes it goes in circles)
Java 8
Maven (you can suggest some plugin)


Based on your tags and content, I made it clear that you are referring to Java code types.  If that's not correct, please edit my edits!

You could check out Classycle. While it's not a tool to directly report unused classes, it can draw whole dependency graph so that you can spot all out of the outliers with too low usage that doesn't meet your liking.
Note that it's a dated tool, though.

Thank you! Isn't there some modern tool as well?
